# Make RDF readable , transform into XML

Tags: c++, xml, file, type-conversion, rdf

Iam currently trying to create a tool which translated RDF files into XML files. I require this in order to edit some files before I convert it back into RDF to be read by my server. I have little experience, but I believe that I must use the RDF structure in my code in order for the converter to read the data and convert it into XML. However, I don't know where to begin. Could someone help me?

Comment: Why would you convert it to XML and then back to RDF? Why can't you use any RDF library to directly modify the data on it's dedicated data structure like triples and resources?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the RDF/XML syntax? It looks like it already addresses your problem. See the W3C recommendation: https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that's so huge actually :( i really don't know what to begin with in order to learn

Comment: The bottom line is that you may not have to convert RDF to XML because one of the RDF serializations is already RDF/XML. Any of the common libraries for handling RDF (e.g., Apache Jena in Java, RDFlib in Python) already create such serialization.